# Dynamically adjusting floating point spinbox increment in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, spinbox

I want to be able to dynamically adjust the increment for my floating point numerical spinbox (`spin1`) below. To do so, I've created a second spin box (`spin2`) that has values `(0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001)`, which determine the step size of `spin1`.

This works fine as long as I always move from coarser to finer increments. It fails when I attempt to move from a finer to a coarser increment because the value gets truncated to the precision of the increment.

Using the code below, here is how the problem can be reproduced:

1. Move `spin1` to `0.2`:

   [image]
2. Increment `spin2`, say to `0.01`:

   [image]
3. Increment `spin1` to `0.21`:

   [image]
4. Decrement `spin2` back to `0.1`:

   [image]
5. Decrement `spin1`:

   [image]

I would expect to see the value `0.11` in `spin1`, but instead I see `0.1`. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Spinbox

def update():
    spin1['increment'] = float(spin2.get())

window = Tk()
spin1 = Spinbox(window, from_=0.0, to=10.0, increment=0.1)
spin2 = Spinbox(window, values=(0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001), command=update)
spin1.pack()
spin2.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Additional observation:

- The spinner always truncates values rather than rounding. So if `spin1` were set to `2.6` in step 3, the final result would still be `0.1`, not `0.2`.

Comment: Try adding `format="%.4f"` to `spin1`.

Comment: @acw1668. Yup. That would do it. Please post an answer when you can. I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `format="%.4f"` (based on the maximum decimal points of `0.0001` from `spin2`) to `spin1`:

```py
spin1 = Spinbox(window, from_=0.0, to=10.0, increment=0.1, format="%.4f")
```